# Are there safari cycling experiences in South Africa?

Tags: touring, travelling

I am looking for first hand experience with cycling among wildlife. Preferably in South Africa but answers from anywhere in Africa would be suitable too.

Is it even possible?

Comment: I know in Kenya even the roads near the wildlife reserves can provide good sightings if you're lucky.  I believe access to the reserves in South Africa can be easier than other countries that require a guide, but are you looking for guided tours or self-guided?

Comment: Thanks for sharing Chris, either guided or self-guided.

Comment: For an overview, you might want to look into Mark Beaumont's *Africa Solo* documentary, book (which I haven't read yet, but have read some of his others) and various interviews.  He [mentions](https://www.cyclinguk.org/cycle/africa-solo) giraffes and elephants at the roadside in Botswana, and tends to give a realistic view of road safety and riding conditions (from a British perspective, perhaps even more so than my own).  But I don't know enough to give a full answer

Comment: Reminds me of this short video clip that went viral a few years back: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=89-yq2jlnnc

Comment: @AndyP: Now put in a lion instead of the antelope!

Comment: Thanks for the reccommendation @ChrisH , I appreciate it.